# Emulate click in Google Console for Chrome settings page

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Google chrome settings page prevents me to delete a default search engine (drop down menu allowing to do so does not show up on click in browser). Yet the path to the hidden #delete button is easy to find in the inspector. My problem is to emulate a click in the console.

I've tried many combinations along the lines of:

> document.querySelector(path).click();

Here's an example with the full JSpath

> document.querySelector("body > settings-ui").shadowRoot.querySelector("#main").shadowRoot.querySelector("settings-basic-page").shadowRoot.querySelector("#basicPage > settings-section.expanded > settings-search-page").shadowRoot.querySelector("#pages > settings-subpage > settings-search-engines-page").shadowRoot.querySelector("settings-search-engines-list:nth-child(11)").shadowRoot.querySelector("#container > iron-list > settings-search-engine-entry:nth-child(3)").shadowRoot.querySelector("#delete").click();

I simply get "undefined" as an error message.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3h8f.png
image description: Here's the front end issue I run into when I try to delete the default browser.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome doesn't allow to remove the default engine: it performs the check explicitly in its [internal C++ code](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:chrome/browser/ui/search_engines/keyword_editor_controller.cc;drc=6430b3e712e4dd44b138d4c02bb1ef315bcb5473;l=70?sq=package:chromium) so you'll have to make another engine a default one beforehand.

And here's a simpler command to delete the engine at index 1, that is the second engine in the list:

```js
chrome.send("removeSearchEngine", [1])
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response! Sadly, the option to make any other browser default is, too, hidden from the front end. Edit/Remove from list are the only to options available to me.

Comment: chrome.send("removeSearchEngine", [1])
works great for all other search engines though, thanks a bunch. Any idea how to select another one as a default browser?

Comment: `chrome.send("setDefaultSearchEngine", [0])` where `0` is the 0-based index of the engine.

Comment: Thanks again @wOwwOm. Sadly, `chrome.send("setDefaultSearchEngine", [X])` does not make the browser in question default. I simply get the `undefined` response. Any other ideas?

Comment: Well, it's the one and only method used by the settings page internally. Open `chrome://policy` and check if there are any related restrictions. This is as far as I can help without trying the same config as yours myself.